# How to freeze graph in tensorflow 1.5 without using bazel?

Tags: python, tensorflow

in tools directory in tensorflow, we have freeze graph python file, that we can use directly, so why do we need bazel, also I tried using that script, and got the following error :

```
    226   elif input_graph:
--> 227     input_graph_def = _parse_input_graph_proto(input_graph, input_binary)
    228   input_meta_graph_def = None
    229   if input_meta_graph:

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py in _parse_input_graph_proto(input_graph, input_binary)
    167   with gfile.FastGFile(input_graph, mode) as f:
    168     if input_binary:
--> 169       input_graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    170     else:
    171       text_format.Merge(f.read(), input_graph_def)

DecodeError: Error parsing message
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need bazel, you can simply execute `python freeze_graph.py` with the appropriate arguments.

About your error, it looks like you're passing a `.pbtxt` file without setting `--input_binary=False`. Sinceit defaults to `True`, the script expects you to pass a `.pb` file. When it tries to decode a `.pbtxt` as binary, errors are raised.